# How to add images in Image Preview Dashlet in Alfresco Share

Tags: image, alfresco-share

Am using Alfresco Share Community Edition 5.0. In this version, Image Preview Dashlet is available by default. I've loaded .JPEG, .GIF and .PNG files in images folder. when i try to add images from Image Preview dashlet , i cant select any one of above mentioned images. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be worth checking the images preview fine through both the Document Library and Document Details pages - if they do then they should show up ok in the Image Preview dashlet. If they don't then it's likely there was a problem generating a thumbnail from the image (hopefully there'll be more info in your alfresco.log).

It's also worth checking the location the dashlet looks for the images. Hover your mouse over the dashlet and click the pencil icon in the top right of the dashlet's title bar. This will allow you to select the path to the folder containing your images.

Comment: Am able to select path (A folder Where i have stored my images under Document Library) using pencil icon. But images inside the folders are not visible in this dialog. And Nothing changed in Image Preview dashlet, after selecting the path. @David Webster

Comment: can you explain me all step?are you using site dashlet?

Answer (score 0):

May be bug.But you should upload files inside documentLibrary of particular site.It is available as site dashlet I guess.I have uploaded pnf and tiff and it was showing in that dashlet.

If you are uploading image inside repo than it will not show that image in dashlet.

Comment: Already, I have created a folder inside documentLibrary. And loaded my images in that folder only. (Probably I've loaded only JPEG,PNG,GIF images). @Krutik Jayswal